# ng2-toasty@4.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.7 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: angular

I have this warning apears when i run npm install

```
ng2-toasty@4.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.7 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

and the package doesn't work.
I tried to install @angular/core@^2.4.7 and @angular/core@^4.0.0 but this generates alot of errors.
any suggestions how to solve this?